# How to increment variable using foreach in smarty?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

This is my assigned variable

```
 {assign var="count" value=0}
```

I put the variable in foreach statement

```
{foreach from=$name item=names}
   {assign var="count" value=$count+1}
{/foreach}
```

Want to display variable in div named "friendsCount"

```
<div class="friendsCount">
   Total friends:{$count}
</div>
```

But when the program error message is displaying " Trying to get property of non-object". Please help me to find a solution. Am using codeigniter

Comment: You can count total items of array with `{$friends|count}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count total items of array with `{$friends|count}`

**Documentation:** http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyFrequentlyAskedQuestions#template-1

Comment: Link is broken. It displays "prout" ("fart" in French). Smarty's humor seems to be very smart!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `""` when you declare variable in smarty. You can simply declare like this.

```
{assign var=count value=0}

{foreach from=$name item=names}
    {assign var=count value=$count+1}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: I removed `" "` then also same error is showing @Arkar Aung